# "alle" vs "all die"

Tags: difference, usage, pronoun

> (a) Ich muss heute Abend alle Hausaufgaben machen.
>
> (b) Ich muss heute Abend all die Hausaufgaben machen.

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen den Bedeutungen von den beiden Sätzen? Drückt "all die" etwas Spezifischeres aus als "alle"?

Auch:

> (c) Ich muss heute Abend alle Hausaufgaben machen, die ich bisher aufgeschoben habe.
>
> (d) Ich muss heute Abend all die Hausaufgaben machen, die ich bisher aufgeschoben habe.

Comment: Beim zweiten Satz kommt bei mir das Gefühl auf als würde da ein Nebensatz fehlen ("Ich muss heut abend all die Hausafgaben machen, die ich bisher aufgeschoben habe."). Ohne den klingt es für mich etwas komisch :/

Comment: @hoffmale Guter Punkt. Ich habe Deinem Vorschlag nach aktualisiert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mit Einschränkung sind sie bedeutungsgleich:

> Ich muss heute Abend alle Hausaufgaben machen, die ich bis jetzt aufgeschoben habe.
>   Ich muss heute Abend all die Hausaufgaben machen, die ich bis jetzt aufgeschoben habe.

Ganz ohne Einschränkung kann nur "alle" stehen. Für diesen Gebrauch eignet sich obiges Beispiel aber nicht wirklich:

> Er stellte allen Menschen dieselbe Frage.

"All die" setzt auf jeden Fall eine Einschränkung voraus. Diese kann entweder direkt im Satz stehen, oder aber es ist - wenn auch nur intuitiv - klar, was diese ist:

> Er stellte all den Menschen dieselbe Frage. ~
>   Er stellte all den Menschen, denen er begegnete, dieselbe Frage.

Der Unterschied ist also technischer Natur.

Answer (score 2):

**alle** 
betont die Gesamtheit im Gegensatz zu einer Teilmenge, während 
**all die**
 die schiere Menge betrachtet (und oft betont). 
An das Beispiel aus der Frage angelehnt:

> Ich muß heute zum Glück nicht **alle** Hausaufgaben machen. Denn für **all die** zusammen brauche ich sicher Stunden.